# how can i (using ajax only), keep the selected value selected after setInterval?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, setinterval

```
  function RecupText2() {
    var ajaxRequest = ajaxFunction();
    ajaxRequest.open("GET","ajax2.php",true);
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if( ajaxRequest.readyState==4 && ajaxRequest.status==200){
            document.getElementById("remplir").innerHTML= ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
var interval = setInterval(RecupText2, 1000);
```

the setinterval updates the select list every second, which changes the selected value to the first option! thank you!

Comment: Either don't replace the whole `innerHTML` or check what the selected value is before replacing it and then set the value back after replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTML5 Data Attribute to store the selected option.
Here; below, is an Example. This example requires & assumes the use of JQuery...

```
        <html>
            <head>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    (function($) {
                        /** THE DOM HAS FULLY LOADED & NOW JQUERY CAN INTERACT WITH IT... */
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            //RESET THE data-selected ATTRIBUTE EACH TIME THE VALUE OF THE SELECT DROP-DOWN CHANGES
                            $("#options-list").on("change", function(evt){
                                $(this).attr("data-selected", currentElem.val());
                            });

                            // MAKE SURE TO SET THE VALUE OF THE SELECT TO THE VALUE OF THE data-selected ATTRIBUTE AT EACH INTERVAL CHANGE
                            // SO WITHIN THE CODE THAT UPDATES THE SELECT, DO LIKE SO
                            $("#options-list").val( $("#options-list").attr("data-selected") );
                        });
                    })(jQuery);

                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <select name="options-list" id="options-list" class="options-list" data-selected="3">
                    <option value="10">Ten</option>
                    <option value="9">Nine</option>
                    <option value="8">Eight</option>
                    <option value="7">Seven</option>
                    <option value="6">Six</option>
                    <option value="5">Five</option>
                    <option value="4">Four</option>
                    <option value="3">Three</option>
                    <option value="2">Two</option>
                    <option value="1">One</option>
                </select>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Hope this helps a bit....

Comment: well it would if it was without using jquery, i shall not use it :toobad but thanks a lot :D